# Magento 2 : Cannot Read Property "quoteData" of undefined

Tags: magento2, cart, javascript, shopping-cart

I was seeing various errors on cart page of Magento 2.1.6.

```
Cannot read property "quoteData" of undefined (quote.js)
Cannot read property 'storeCode' of undefined (url-builder.js)
Cannot convert undefined or null to object (customer-addresses.js)
```

Incase someone else sees these errors, for me they were caused by removing certain blocks from checkout in XML.

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.coupon" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.crosssell" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.order.actions.gift_options" remove="true"/>
```

I fixed by re-inserting blocks and hiding relevant sections with css.

Answer (score 5):

For my case it was this block

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping" remove="true"/>
```

I removed that line and I overwrote `shipping.phtml` on my theme to remove the shipping address and to keep the checkoutConfig and the JavaScript. It's totally stupid to include the script in a part of the view and depend on it on other parts. Just like the rest of everything stupid with Magento

Comment: The fact that you don't understand something doesn't mean it's stupid. Maybe you should do a pull request and fix that misconception yourself instead of complaining.

Comment: @YonnTrimoreau The fact that magento include the shipping module scripts everywhere on the website makes magento stupid and fragile.

Comment: Maybe stupid, on some aspects I agree with you, but still it is the top 1 e-commerce platform of the world in traffic. Must not be that stupid and fragile...