# Cannot Read Property “quoteData” of undefined magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2.2

How do I fix Magento 2.2.2

> Cannot Read Property “quoteData” of undefined

Issue? Please give me flexible solution for this issue.

Comment: Refer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176082/magento-2-cannot-read-property-quotedata-of-undefined) link.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost impossible to identify the source of this error based just on this message. Most likely you are overriding/extending (mixin) some file, which being called on page where it is not intended.

Maybe instead of declaring some of your js library at requirejs, put in view/frontent/templates, as an example bellow.

```
<?php
$displayOnThisPage = $block->someFunctionWhichReturnsTrueFalse();

?>
<?php if ($block->isCheckoutPage()): ?>
<!--- some html if this is checkout page --->
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($displayOnThisPage ): ?>
    <script>
        require.config({
            config: {
                mixins: {
                    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator': {
                        'Vendor_Module/js/validator-mixin': true
                    }
                }
            },
            map: {
                "*": {}
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
            <?php if ($block->isCheckoutPage()): ?>

            <?php else: ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
            }
        }
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```